# The process window is closing

Tags: c#

I run ruby script (__FileName) from my app, here is the code

```
private void runToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "ruby.exe",
        Arguments = __FileName,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        UseShellExecute = false
    };

    var p = Process.Start(psi);

    textBox2.Text = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() + p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
}
```

In this case, the process window appears and immediately disappears, even if within the script there is the command "gets".

How can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe this helps: `Process.WaitForExit()` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -1):

> You have to call `WaitForExit` so your code blocks until the process.

If it helps, here is a snippet you can use to run a process silently and get its output.

https://gist.github.com/augustoproiete/5134f24de133f7723809

Comment: I tried to insert `p.WaitForExit();` after `var p = Process.Start(psi);` - no effect.